# upload app via Xcode, can't find on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Pardon me for beginner's question, I already uploaded the app successfully, see 1st screenshot, but can't seem to find it anywhere in iTunesConnect, see 2nd screenshot. And of course, I can't submit for review. Any tip? Tks

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can take some hours before the build is processed and available. Do you use the same developer id for Xcode and itunesconnect?

Comment: click on activity tab on top and you will find your build under all builds and it's current status. It takes some time before it's processed completely.

Comment: @Joakim yes I did use the same dev id for both

Comment: @AmodGokhale as my second screenshot above shows, there's no build shown there, how long does it normally take before showing, 1 hour or 10 hours?

Comment: @TaxiNoiBaiHaNoi in my experience it's usually processed less than an hour. Can you check if you received any email from apple for completion or failure? an email is send by them in any case.